# Reset datetime-local by Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, datetime

How I can reset the value for a Datatime-local to a default value : "mm/dd/yyyy --:-- --"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addMinutes(date, minutes) {
        var newdate = date.getTime() + minutes * 60000
        var temp = new Date(newdate).toISOString();
        return temp.toString().substr(0, 19);
    }

    $('#SelectIssuePriority').change(function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val().split('|');
        if (selectedValue != null && selectedValue != '') {
            var newDate = addMinutes(new Date(), selectedValue[1]);
            $('#EstimateTime').val(newDate);
        } else {
            $('#EstimateTime').val("mm/dd/yyyy --:-- --");
        }
    });
</script>
```

I put this code to work:  jsfiddle.net/2BfnE

Comment: what is your expected default value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it not possible to change the date format of **`HTML5 input type=“date”`**.

On a quick research I found out this [**SO question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format) is some what similar to yours.

Since you have tagged `jQuery` why don't you use the the [**Datepicker**](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) of `jQuery UI`.  Where it is quite easy to deal with formats.

Comment: I have been using this code. I updated it and it have working.

Comment: @Coelho Oh, you got it.  out of curiosity, can you share it in JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, try this instead, just leave it empty:

```
$("#EstimateTime").val("");
```

It will reset to default.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are a pair of brackets missing:

```
$('#EstimateTime').val(("mm/dd/yyyy --:-- --"));
```